# Poisson Distribution more than 2 raindrops will fall on the square inch

Tags: probability

Assume that raindrops fall on a particular square inch of a city block according to a Poisson process will an average of 2 raindrops per second. Find the probability that more than 2 raindrops will fall on the square inch during a 5-second time interval.

What I got for this was:

$$1 - [P(Y=0)+P(Y=1)+P(Y=2)]$$

basically: 
$$1- \left[
\left(\frac{5(2)^2}{2!}\right)\left(e^{-2*5}\right) 
+ \left(\frac{5(2)^1}{1!}\right)\left(e^{-2*5}\right) 
+ \left(\frac{5(2)^0}{0!}\right)\left(e^{-2*5}\right)\right]$$

is this correct or am I think about this totally wrong?

Comment: please note that you have enough reputation to vote up any answer as well as accept (and at 125 reputation you can vote down as well!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed $$P(Y>2)= 1 - [P(Y=0)+P(Y=1)+P(Y=2)]$$

Then if you mean $$1-\left[\frac{(5\cdot2)^2}{2!}e^{-2\cdot5} + \frac{(5\cdot2)^1}{1!}e^{-2\cdot5} + \frac{(5\cdot2)^0}{0!}e^{-2\cdot5}\right]$$ your answer is correct (be careful with the parentheses in your expression).